# Spring Cloud Contract tests work with Maven but not when run with JUnit

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, spring-cloud-contract

I have a Maven project with two modules, one for the **producer** and another for **consumer**.

```
Project
-- Producer module
-- Consumer module
```

The **consumer** contains a dependency to the producer stubs, i.e.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>producer-application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>stubs</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the integration tests are configured so `StubRunner` uses classpath scanning, i.e.

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.CLASSPATH,
        ids = "com.example:producer-application:+:8090"
)
```

During build, the integration tests for the **consumer** are executed correctly but if I try to run the tests locally with JUnit through the IDE (IntelliJ), the stubs are not found and tests fail.

Is this an issue on how the project is structured? If so, is there something I can change to have it run without changing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classpath will not work from ide cause e.g. Intellij does not add the stubs jar to the classpath. It's a known issue with the ides.

Comment: Is there an issue tracking this in the project? Would like to have a look and brainstorm.

Comment: Which project? Spring cloud contract? Yes just go to github and type in the project name

Comment: I couldn't find any specific ticket (in the SCC board) mentioning this issue with the IDEs. But now I'm wondering if this an issue in SCC or rather an issue in IntelliJ.

Comment: That's an issue in the ide